# Facebook API so slow

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the PHP SDK and it's really slow, for example to run this:

```
      try {
        $me = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        if ($me) {
          return true;
        }
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        return false;
      }
```

I bench marked it at 0.8605.  This adds up to a lot, is there a better way to query this data?

Comment: how much data are you requesting at a time that it "adds up"? What sorts of requests are you making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the response and then subscribe to [real-time updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) to get notified if that data ever changes.  You could also load it asynchronously through javascript in the browser.  I haven't seen that slow of a response time from /me though so it could be a temporary issue.  Are you sure its not network response time? What country are you requesting it from?